# Vue two-way binding in 'transparent' wrapped input component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am writing a small wrapper for a `<input>` component.
I was following the documentation and this 
[tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/25).

However I am having issues with the two-way binding.
I expect my component to work with `v-model`. The binding seems to work fine for updating the value, but when I change the value itself the component doesn't update. I've also [read about transparent wrappers](https://zendev.com/2018/05/31/transparent-wrapper-components-in-vue.html), which seems to be my issue here.

Simple example:

```
<template id="numInput" :v-on="listeners">
  <div>
    <!-- note the div here, it works without, but that's not what I want -->
    <input ref:inp type="number" :value="num" @input="updateSelf($event.target.value)" @blur="reset" :class="{rc: isNegative}" />
  </div>
</template>
```

You can find the whole code example [here](https://codepen.io/luaiodu/pen/aaKdXJ).

The binding works one way (modifying the text input). But the input component doesn't get updated the other way (button klick in example)

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom input components should be stateless (unless you have a reason not to); what this means is the value of the component should be provided by a prop and not local state (data). Your `<num-input>` component lacks a `value` prop which is needed for `v-model` to work.

Also you might want to set the [`inheritAttrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) option to false and bind `$attrs` manually since you've wrapped the input element in a div.

Here's a small example of how it should be:

```js
Vue.component('num-input', {
  template: '#numInput',
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: ['value'],
  computed: {
    isNegative() {
      return this.value < 0;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      // You can conditionally do this after validation
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
    },
    onBlur() {
      if (this.isNegative) {
        this.$emit('input', 0);
      }
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    num: 0,
  },
});
```

```css
.negative { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <num-input v-model="num"></num-input>
  <button @click="num++">+1</button>
  <p>{{ num }}</p>
</div>

<template id="numInput">
  <div>
    <input type="number" :value="value" @input="onInput" @blur="onBlur" :class="{ negative: isNegative }" v-bind="$attrs">
  </div>
</template>
```

I haven't coerced the value emitted by the `input` event to a number (it's a string), but I'll leave this up to you.

Comment: Great! Thanks also for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things going wrong here, but the most fundamental is that you are mixing nom and num in your code.  I reworked your component a little and turned your num data into a property and then bound to it in your main app.

Here is your reworked code...

```
Vue.config.devtools = true;

// global component registration
Vue.component('num-input', {
  template: '#numInput', 
  props: ['value'],
  computed: {
    isNegative: function() {
      console.log('num: ' + this.value)
      return this.value < 0;
    },
    listeners: function () {
      return this.$listeners;
    },
  },
  methods: {  
    reset () {
      if (this.isNegative) {
        this.$emit('input', 0)        
      }
    }
  },
});

 new Vue({
   el: '#container',
   data: {
     num: 0,
   },
   methods: {
     increaseBy1() {
       this.num++;
       console.log("increased by 1");
     },
   },
 });
```

To view the code and the html binding I forked your codepen and it can be found at...

https://codepen.io/peterpde/pen/BOVQzg

Comment: In your example, changing the input doesn't change the `p` tag. You also have to add this piece of code : `@input="num = $event"` into `num-input`.

There also something else that is wrong : the `updateSelf` mutates the num prop.

Comment: You are right.  I was too focused on getting the button to work.  Let me look at again and make edits.  Thanks.

Comment: Changed code to fix the many issues pointed out my @ThomasLombart.  Thanks again.